# how to toggle between button display

Tags: html, css

```css
.b1, .b2, .b3{
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: .5rem;
    }
    .b1{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    }
    .b2{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    }
    .b3{
    background-color: yellow;
    color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <button class="b1">Approve</button>
    <button class="b2">Deny</button>
    <button class="b3">Void</button>
```

I need a function whereby any button clicked makes the other two buttons `display:none` without being able to be displayed again even if that same button is clicked a second time.

Only `.b3` when clicked twice should make other buttons reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this in Jquery this way. Is this what you mean toggle the yellow only.

```js
$(".b1").click(function(){
  $(".b2, .b3 ").hide()

});

$(".b2").click(function(){
  $(".b1, .b3 ").hide()

});
  
  $(".b3").click(function(){
  $(".b1, .b2 ").toggle()
 
});
```

```css
.b1, .b2, .b3{
padding: 1rem;
margin: .5rem;
}
.b1{
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
.b2{
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
.b3{
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="b1">Approve</button>
<button class="b2">Deny</button>
<button class="b3">Void</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is on click event handler for button.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
buttons.forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", function onClick(event) {
    buttons.forEach((btn) => {
      if (event.target.className !== btn.className) {
        btn.style.display =
          event.target.className === "b3" && btn.style.display === "none"
            ? "inline"
            : "none";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.b1, .b2, .b3{
padding: 1rem;
margin: .5rem;
}
.b1{
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
.b2{
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
.b3{
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="b1">Approve</button>
<button class="b2">Deny</button>
<button class="b3">Void</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addEventListener` javascript function to add interaction on button click.
The `onClick` method will call the function `hideButtons`, the function is passed to an anonymous function to avoid the call on page load.

```js
var clicked = false
var b1 = document.querySelector(".b1")
var b2 = document.querySelector(".b2")
var b3 = document.querySelector(".b3")

function hideButtons(button1, button2) {
    button1.style.display = (clicked ? "inline" : "none") 
    button2.style.display = (clicked ? "inline" : "none") 
    clicked = !clicked
}

b1.addEventListener("click", () => {hideButtons(b2, b3)})
b2.addEventListener("click", () => {hideButtons(b1, b3)})
b3.addEventListener("click", () => {hideButtons(b2, b1)})
```

```css
.b1, .b2, .b3{
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}
.b1{
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
.b2{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
.b3{
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="b1">Approve</button>
<button class="b2">Deny</button>
<button class="b3">Void</button>
```

Comment: Only the yellow button should have the function to re-show the remaining buttons after being clicked the second time

Answer (score 0):

```js
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (button of buttons) {
    button.onclick =  clicked;
}

function clicked(event) {
  for (button of buttons) {
    button.style.display = "none";
  }
    event.target.style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.b1, .b2, .b3{
padding: 1rem;
margin: .5rem;
}
.b1{
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
.b2{
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
.b3{
background-color: yellow;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="b1">Approve</button>
<button class="b2">Deny</button>
<button class="b3">Void</button>
```

Add the event listener to the buttons which will trigger when the button is clicked via `button.onclick = functionName` declaration. This function will hide all buttons, then show the one you clicked using the `event.target` property.

You can use this with more buttons as well if you need just by adding new buttons to the HTML.

Comment: I need the buttons to re-show if the yellow void button is clicked again, please